# How to get fully visible cells/items in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view, gridlayoutmanager, onscrolllistener

I have a screen where items/cells are designed in the 2x2 grid form. What I want to do is I want to fire APIs on item visibility/impression when `RecyclerView` scrolls up/down.

As my list is pretty huge

For example scenario is,

1. On the first load, it shows e.g. 6 (3x2) items/cells. Then, fire API for all those 6 items as those are fully visible.
2. On scroll up, e.g. it shows another 2 items and above/top 2 items go out of screen hence, it should fire API for newly 2 items.

This way I want to complete traversal of the entire list and call API on newly found items.

What I tried is,

1. Below methods of GridLayoutManager not worked for me as each of them giving different values and seems to be random

> int findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
>
> int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
>
> int findLastVisibleItemPosition();
>
> int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

2. Checking bounds of `View` lying on screen with the help of `Rect | getGlobalVisibleRect()` but that is also not working inside `onScrolled() | OnScrollStateChanged()`

Please suggest approach where I can get the correct index of the fully visible cell.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create separate thread for the action of `onScrolled() | onScrollStateChanged()`. It will solve your problem.